# How to prevent terminal window from closing when Linux Bash Script terminates?

Tags: linux, bash

I've written a simple bash script for deleting some temporary files that match a certain pattern:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/some_project/some_dir
rm */*.xml
```

I've saved it as 'script', chmodded it to `+x` via terminal. Now when I double click this file, I get the option to Run it in terminal or display its output. If I click Run in terminal, the script correctly works, however the terminal window closes immediately. I'd rather the window stay open so I can see if there were any errors (and possibly get rm to display names of deleted files if possible).

I'm looking for a simple way to keep the terminal from closing until a keypress happens.. is there such a way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `read` command to the end of your script. It will wait for a complete line of input (that is, <kbd>Enter</kbd> key).

Answer (score 9):

```
read -rn1
```

See [`help read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) for more information.

Comment: I like the solution to the body character minimum message, lol

Comment: `-r`: If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character. `-n`: read returns after reading *nchars* characters rather than waiting for a complete line of input. `1`: the *nchars*.